# Pointer changes value after storing it in an object (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, reference

I notice (to me) weird behavior. If I initialize a `DerivedClass` and pass a pointer of another class (`player`) to it, then it receives the right pointer value. However, if I then try to use that pointer, later on in `check_pointer_of_player()`, the value changed. I do not understand this behavior, and I would like to know how I can alternatively achieve the goal: use functions of `player` within the `DerivedClass`.

```
class DerivedClass : public ParentClass {
    protected:
        Player* player;
    public:
        DerivedClass(Coord p, Player* player) : ParentClass(p) {
            std::cout << "During intialization the pointer value is: " << player << "\n";
            player = player;
        }

        void check_pointer_of_player() {
            std::cout << "Now the pointer value is: " << player << "\n";
        }
```

As I wrote, during initialization the pointer value is correct, but later when I call this class' function `check_pointer_value()` it returns a different value. Below is the output visible.

> During intialization the pointer value is: 0x7f908f558710
>
> Now the pointer value is: 0x7fff41140004

How do I still achieve my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the body of the constructor, the parameter `player` is shadowing the member `player`, so you are not actually assigning the parameter to the member. This is why *only* the constructor shows the correct value of `player` when you print it out.

You can disambiguate like this:

```
DerivedClass(Coord p, Player* player) : ParentClass(p) {
    std::cout << "During intialization the pointer value is: " << player << "\n";
    this->player = player;
}
```

Or just give the parameter a different name:

```
DerivedClass(Coord p, Player* player_param) : ParentClass(p) {
    std::cout << "During intialization the pointer value is: " << player << "\n";
    player = player_param;
}
```

The best option would be to use a member initializer list, where the names can actually be the same, so you could do:

```
DerivedClass(Coord p, Player* player) : ParentClass(p), player(player) {
    std::cout << "During intialization the pointer value is: " << player << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Or put player(player) next to ParentClass(p)

Comment: @QuentinUK Of course, that's a much better solution. added it, thanks :)

Comment: Oh, woah, now I feel really stupid for not finding this out, ha ha! Well, what can I say, thanks a lot. It works like a charm now and your answer is really clear!

Comment: Good, I'm glad it makes sense. Happy to help :)